# imageview with only color rounded corner

Tags: android, imageview, rounded-corners

i'm trying to have some colored rounded corner imageviews!!!

i define my imageviews like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game_play_color_image_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/game_play_values_colors_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/soft_corner"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

and the background defines :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" >
</padding>

<corners android:radius="5dp" >
</corners>
```

and i set the color of my imageviews like this

(color is my own class which it has 3 property as you can see)

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue()));
```

but the problem is, my imageviews don't have a rounded corner!!

what is wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use cornor specific tag in `corners`, this should work `<corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting the background again... if you already have a background resource you replacing it. If you want a imageView to have a solid color as the background of your imageview try using the `@drawable/soft_corner` as `imageResource` and set the color of the rectangle with shapes to be transparent with `android:color/transparent`

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me so you use this it will help you

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke

    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#2f6699" />
<corners 

    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom ImageView for your requirement. Check [this](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)  for details.

Comment: I can't use that for background color! the corners are nor rounded and the only way is to input bitmap to that

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean.